# Python: How to create a 2D list that each cell is holding two different values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pandas, tuples

I would like to create (and SET/GET) a 2D matrix like

```
   mat=
           0      1         2
     0    a|00    b|01     c|02
     1    x|10    y|11     z|12
```

and then be able to SET/GET each a, b, ... and/or the numbers independently. Should I insert a tuple in the list or insert another list in the list? any idea?

Comment: It sounds like you want a "3D" martix, right?(The third dimention is a list/tuple/array of lengh 2) I think you can do it by the same way that you use to build the original "2D" matrix.

Comment: creative point of view! tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question right you'll like to create a data frame holding tuples?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0':[("a",01), ("x",10)], '1':[("b",02), ("y",11)], '2':[("c",02), ("z",12)]})    
print df

         0        1        2
0   (a, 1)   (b, 2)   (c, 2)
1  (x, 10)  (y, 11)  (z, 12)
```

Using the built in function `zip` and inverse it `(*)` will unpack your tuples:

```
print zip(*df["0"])
[('a', 'x'), (1, 10)]
```